# bigfoot behaviour for footnotes as paragraph

Tags: bigfoot

I am setting up a critical edition with long footnote texts. So
I need all footnotes to appear in a paragraph. So I explored the tex helo and used bigfoot package with paragraph option. However I see the behaviour varies based on the length of the footnote text. For example following code works properly

```
\documentclass[twoside,11pt,openany]{book}
\usepackage[para]{bigfoot}
\expandafter\def\csname @makefnbreak\endcsname{\unskip\linebreak[0]}
\DeclareNewFootnote[para]{default}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand\@makefntext[1]{%
 \setlength{\parindent}{4 em}
 \small#1}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
   Can I\footnote{\textbf{ONE} akjfsandfjkdsn kajdnf kjadsnc kjna kjdnakjndf akjdn kfjnd kjanf adkn kjnfakdjnakjfnak djn fkajnakjfna kjfnadskjfnadkjfndak jnfka.}
 get all the footnotes as paragraphs\footnote{\textbf{TWO} Pellentesque cursus luctus mauris. Quisque ullamcorper placerat ipsum. Cras nibh. Morbi vNunc elementum fermentum wisi.}
  instead of one below the other\footnote{\textbf{Three} } irrespective of the size of the footnote\footnote{\textbf{FOUR} Pellentesque cursus luctus mauris. Quisque ullamcorper placerat ipsum. Cras nibh. Morbi vel justo vitae lacus tincidunt ultrices.orta vehicula. Quisque ullamcorper placerat ipsum. quis }
  \end{document}
```

The output is proper as expected.[image: Footnotes of shorter length texts appear as Paragrahs as expected]

However when I increase the size of the footnote text, for example say the second footnote text is increased it breaks at some point and throw out the output as individual footnotes instead of paragraphs as given int he below example.

```
\documentclass[twoside,11pt,openany]{book}
\usepackage[para]{bigfoot}
\expandafter\def\csname @makefnbreak\endcsname{\unskip\linebreak[0]}
\DeclareNewFootnote[para]{default}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand\@makefntext[1]{%
 \setlength{\parindent}{4 em}
 \small#1}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
   Can I\footnote{\textbf{ONE} akjfsandfjkdsn kajdnf kjadsnc kjna kjdnakjndf akjdn kfjnd kjanf adkn kjnfakdjnakjfnak djn fkajnakjfna kjfnadskjfnadkjfndak jnfka.}
   get all the footnotes as paragraphs\footnote{\textbf{TWO} Pellentesque cursus luctus mauris. Quisque ullamcorper placerat ipsum. Cras nibh. Morbi vNunc elementum fermentum wisi.ellentesque cursus luctus mauris. Quisque ullamcorper placerat ipsum. Cras nibh. Morbi vel justo vitae lacus tincidunt ultrices.orta vehicula. Quisque ullamcorper placerat ipsum. quis ellentesque cursus luctus mauris. Quisque ullamcorper placerat ipsum. Cras nibh. Morbi vel justo vitae lacus tincidunt ultrices.orta vehicula. Quisque ullamcorper placerat ipsum. quis ellentesque cursus luctus mauris. Quisque ullamcorper placerat ipsum. Cras nibh. Morbi vel justo vitae lacus tincidunt ultrices.orta vehicula. Quisque ullamcorper placerat ipsum. quis ellentesque cursus luctus mauris. Quisque ullamcorper placerat ipsum. Cras nibh. Morbi vel justo vitae lacus tincidunt ultrices.orta vehicula. Quisque ullamcorper placerat ipsum. quis ellentesque cursus luctus mauris. Quisque ullamcorper placerat ipsum. Cras nibh. Morbi vel justo vitae lacus tincidunt ultrices.orta vehicula. Quisque ullamcorper placerat ipsum. quis }
   instead of one below the other\footnote{\textbf{Three} } irrespective of the size of the footnote\footnote{\textbf{FOUR} Pellentesque cursus luctus mauris. Quisque ullamcorper placerat ipsum. Cras nibh. Morbi vel justo vitae lacus tincidunt ultrices.orta vehicula. Quisque ullamcorper placerat ipsum. quis }
  \end{document}
```

[image: Footnotes of longer text lengths does not appear as paragraphs]

I tried to modify the values of penalty but that does not seem to help

```
\footnotewidowpenalty=-2
\footnoteclubpenalty=-2
\finalfootnotewidowpenalty=-2
\interfootnotelinepenalty=-2
```

Any help on this is appreciated.

Comment: In this question the package used was  bigfoot version 2.1 . However when I tried to use bigfoot version 1.25 for the second scenario given above it seems to work fine. Is this a probable bug got introduced in version 2.1 ? Is it recommended to go for 1.25 version?